# Django legacy database migration of many to many intermediate table

Tags: django, sequelize.js, database-migration

Legacy DB migration to Django (v1.11) (from Sequelize).

An intermediary table in the database has no id (primary key attribute) as Sequelize doesn't require it, but seems it is compulsory in Django.

Current Django setup:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updatedAt', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Addresses'

class CustomerExecutive(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField('Address', through='AddressCustomerExecutiveMapping')
createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now_add=True)
updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updatedAt', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CustomerExecutives'

class AddressCustomerExecutiveMapping(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address,  db_column='addressId', primary_key=True)
    customer_executive = models.ForeignKey(CustomerExecutive, db_column='customerExecutiveId', primary_key=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updatedAt', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'AddressCustomerExecutiveMapping'
    unique_together = (('address', 'customer_executive'),)
```

If `primary_key` is not specified on `AddressCustomerExecutiveMapping.address` or `AddressCustomerExecutiveMapping.customer_executive` it gives a primary key required error and if specified, I'm unable to add duplicate values in the column (not many to many then).

How can I solve this?

Comment: remove the primary key from both of fields

Comment: As said, it gives a primary key required error .

Comment: i run, it's working for me, just try remigrate the db

Comment: After removing the primary_key attributes, migrations work but as there is already data present in the table it is unable to create an id attribute on it. Fails after asking for a default value (if given 9090909) fails later saying that primary key cannot be duplicate

Comment: for that you have write down the script whick will change the value. make a function in migration file which generate unique no and pass that function in default, these code will go in side migrations